# Django unit testing Sekizai and django cms

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-cms, django-sekizai

How can I write tests in django ?
I read the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/

But we use django-cms and sekizai so when I do a simple test like:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class AccessTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs a client.
        self.client = Client()

    def test_details(self):
        # Issue a GET request.
        response = self.client.get('/')

        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/maazza/PycharmProjects/django_my_app/search_engine/tests.py", line 18, in test_details
    response = self.client.get('/')   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 439, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 244, in get
    return self.request(**r)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 381, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 84, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 33, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({})))   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 62, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 62, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 62, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py", line 106, in render
    return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py", line 74, in render_tag
    if not validate_context(context):   File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/django_my_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py", line 28, in validate_context
    "You must enable the 'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai' template " TemplateSyntaxError: You must enable the 'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai' template context processor or use 'sekizai.context.SekizaiContext' to render your templates.
```

> You must enable the 'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai'

Concerning this part I have `sekizai.context_processors.sekizai` in my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://racingtadpole.com/blog/testing-django-cms-sites/

> This was confusing because I was using sekizai correctly in my
>   template.
>
> This post pointed me in the right direction here. The problem was
>   Django was raising an exception but I was never getting to see it –
>   just this much less helpful message.
>
> This Stackoverflow post explained how to enable logging of errors. I
>   copied in the changes to settings.py, wrapping them inside the if
>   'test' statement.
>
> Then when I ran
>
> ./manage.py test
>
> I got a much more useful error message: I had forgotten to set up a
>   table that my template was assuming would exist. Easily fixed!
>
> Hope that helps someone else.

I needed to add some fixtures for it to work.

EDIT:
Ok after a lot of research I found out that despite the above blog I had a different problem.

Thanks to this answer and this doc I knew I had to do it like this :

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from cms.test_utils.testcases import CMSTestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from cms.models import Page
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^search_engine/', include('search_engine.urls')),
    url(r'', include('cms.urls')),
)


class AccessTest(CMSTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs a client.
        p = Page.objects.create(site_id=settings.SITE_ID, template='home_page.html')
        p.publish()
        self.client = Client()

    @override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='search_engine.tests')
    def test_details(self):
        # Issue a GET request.
        response = self.client.get('/')

        # Check that the response is 200 OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

[How to unit test Django-CMS extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625008/how-to-unit-test-django-cms-extensions)
and http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/testing.html <= somehow this is only readable in 'lastest'

> 8.1.1. Resolving View Names
>
> Your apps need testing, but in your live site they aren’t in urls.py
>   as they are attached to a CMS page. So if you want to be able to use
>   reverse() in your tests, or test templates that use the url template
>   tag, you need to hook up your app to a special test version of urls.py
>   and tell your tests to use that.
>
> So you could create myapp/tests/test_urls.py with the following code:
>
> from django.contrib import admin from django.conf.urls import url,
>   patterns, include
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
>       url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
>       url(r'', include('cms.urls')), )
>
> And then in your tests you can plug this in with the
>   override_settings() decorator:
>
> from django.test.utils import override_settings from
>   cms.test_utils.testcases import CMSTestCase
>
> class MyappTests(CMSTestCase):
>
> ```
> @override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='myapp.tests.test_urls')
> def test_myapp_page(self):
>     test_url = reverse('myapp_view_name')
>     # rest of test as normal
> ```
>
> If you want to the test url conf throughout your test class, then you
>   can use apply the decorator to the whole class:
>
> from django.test.utils import override_settings from
>   cms.test_utils.testcases import CMSTestCase
>
> @override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='myapp.tests.test_urls') class
>   MyappTests(CMSTestCase):
>
> ```
> def test_myapp_page(self):
>     test_url = reverse('myapp_view_name')
>     # rest of test as normal
> ```

Answer (score 3):

To solve the sekizai error, this is what I did:

```
from django.test import TestCase                                                
from sekizai.context import SekizaiContext                                      

from cms.api import add_plugin                                                  
from cms.models import Placeholder  
# Put class def here

def test_plugin(self):                                               
    placeholder = Placeholder.objects.create(slot='test')                   
    model_inst = add_plugin(placeholder,                                    
        cms_plugins.MyPlugin, 'en')                     
    context = SekizaiContext()                                              

    html = model_inst.render_plugin(context=context)                                                                                    
    self.assertTrue(len(html) > 0)
```

It was a case of making sure the seikizai context processor was being used during rendering of the plugin.